# P(X_{t+1}} = k | X_t \neq k) in a Markov Chain.

Tags: markov-chains

Let $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Markov chain with transition matrix P, initial distribution $\mu$ and state space $\chi$.

I know that for $k \in \chi, \mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k | X_t =k) = P(k,k)$.
I want to know how to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k | X_t \neq k)$

My initial idea was:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k | X_t \neq k) = \sum_{x \in \chi\\, x \neq k}\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k | X_t = x)\mathbb{P}(X_t = x) =\sum_{x \in \chi\\, x \neq k} P(x,k)\mu_t(x) $$

Is this correct?

Comment: What you have calculate is $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k ,X_t \neq k)$ instead of $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k | X_t \neq k)$

Comment: You are right. So, I can use the result and state: $$\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k|X_t \neq k) = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} =k, X_t \neq k)}{1- \mathbb{P}(X_t =k)} $$ ?

Comment: Yes, just divide by $P(X_t \neq k)$.

Answer (score 0):

By mystake I ended up calculating $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k, X_t \neq k)$ instead of $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k| X_t \neq k)$ like geetha290krm noticed.
So, the correct answer is:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = k|X_t \neq k) &= \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} =k, X_t \neq k)}{\mathbb{P}(X_t \neq k)}\\
&= \dfrac{\sum_{x \in \chi, x \neq k} P(x,k)\mu_t(x)}{1- \mathbb{P}(X_t =k)}
\end{align}